# How to select or find child node in a treeview

Tags: .net, asp.net, treeview

I am able to find a parent node using the following code :

```
TreeNode node = TreeViewProducts.FindNode(nodeID);
```

Similarly if I want to find a child node in a treeview how do I do that.

Is there a way to find it as above rather than looping through all the nodes in the treeview

Thanks

Comment: That doesn't find a parent node, it just finds a node.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ChildNodes` collection.

```
TreeNode node = TreeViewProducts.FindNode(nodeID);
foreach (var childNode in node.ChildNodes)
{

}
```