# How to search child nods in a treeview

Tags: c#

I tride it in this way,

```
private void btnFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < treeView1.Nodes.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
        treeView1.Nodes[i].BackColor = Color.Empty;
    }
    var result = from TreeNode node in treeView1.Nodes
                 where node.Text.Contains( Convert.ToString(txtFind.Text))
                 select node.Index;

    foreach (int search in result)
    {
        treeView1.Nodes[search].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
}
```

But in this way I can find only parent nodes. Is there a proper way to do this

Comment: There is a similar question.. Try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762674/how-to-select-or-find-child-node-in-a-treeview

Answer (score 3):

You can have a method to process the TreeView and then another to recursively call the child nodes. This will load _matchingNodes with all of the nodes that match your text.

```
Private List<TreeNode> _matchingNodes; 

// Process the TreeView.
private void ProcessTreeView(TreeView treeView, String FindText)
{
   _matchingNodes = new List<TreeNode>();

  // Process each node recursively.
   foreach (TreeNode n in treeView.Nodes)
   {
      if(n.Text.Contains(FindText))
        _matchingNodes.Add(n);

      ProcessRecursive(n, FindText);
   }

}

private void ProcessRecursive(TreeNode treeNode, String FindText)
{

  // Process each node recursively.
   foreach (TreeNode n in treeNode.Nodes)
   {
      if(n.Text.Contains(FindText))
        _matchingNodes.Add(n);

      ProcessRecursive(n, FindText);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private void btnFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CallRecursive(treeView1);
        }
        private void PrintRecursive(TreeNode treeNode)
        {

            if (treeNode.Text.Contains(txtFind.Text.ToString()))
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(treeNode.Text);
                treeNode.BackColor = Color.Blue;
            }
            else
            {
                treeNode.BackColor = Color.Empty;
            }
            // Print each node recursively.

            foreach (TreeNode tn in treeNode.Nodes)
            {

                PrintRecursive(tn);

            }

        }

        // Call the procedure using the TreeView.

        private void CallRecursive(TreeView treeView)
        {

            // Print each node recursively.

            TreeNodeCollection nodes = treeView.Nodes;

            foreach (TreeNode n in nodes)
            {

                PrintRecursive(n);

            }

        }
```

I solved It Like this and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

TreeView.nodes.find(nodeName,1)

The numeral 1 specifies to look at all child nodes too.  A 0 means say to not include children.  Only tested in Powershell.

Perhaps not so helpful for searching the text of the nodes but hopefully you can obtain the node name.