# How to find a specific treenode using key or value , among all nodes of a treeview

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I was trying this but, this method is not searching in child nodes

```
TreeNode tr = tree.Nodes.OfType<TreeNode>().FirstOrDefault(node => node.Value.Equals("mytext"));
TreeNode[] t= tree.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>().Where(r1 => r1.Value == "mytext").ToArray();

-root
 -child1
   -A
   -B
 -child2
   -C
```

I want to search C, how will i do it?

Comment: May be this link helps you - [http://stackoverflow.com/a/14111937/2794280](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14111937/2794280)

Comment: It's true. You are searching only in roots; you need a recursive function. Can you provide a tree sample in the previous post?

Comment: @IkramTurgunbaev That's a sample recursion for a TreeNode, but is missing the search condition. The recursive method in that answer should be modified to add `, Func<TreeNode, bool> condition` but is a good starting point anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You have started correctly, `tree.Nodes.OfType<TreeNode>()` will give you all the parent node collection, but you need to dig deep and get the `TreeNodes` which are child nodes of parent. Suppose you have treenode defined like this:-

```
<asp:TreeView ID="tree" runat="server">
    <Nodes>
         <asp:TreeNode Value="Parent1" Expanded="True" Text="Child1">
              <asp:TreeNode Value="Child1A" Text="A" />
              <asp:TreeNode Value="Child1B" Text="B" />
          </asp:TreeNode>
          <asp:TreeNode Value="Parent2" Expanded="True" Text="Child2">
              <asp:TreeNode Value="Child2A" Text="C"></asp:TreeNode>
          </asp:TreeNode>
    </Nodes>
</asp:TreeView>
```

You can get the parent Nodes *Parent1*, *Parent2* by using `tree.Nodes.OfType<TreeNode>()` but to get all the child nodes you can flatten the collection using [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) and finally filter the collecion based on text like this:-

```
var result = tree.Nodes.OfType<TreeNode>()
                 .SelectMany(x => x.ChildNodes.OfType<TreeNode>())
                 .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Text == "C");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a recursive function that returns the nodes matching your criteria. If you want to make it TreeNode specific, you have a decent starting point in Ikram's comment to your question.

If you want a more generic/resuable recursive, check this function and modify to your needs.

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Recursive<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childSelector, Func<T, bool> condition = null)
    {
        foreach (T item in source)
        {
            bool shouldAdd = true;
            if (condition != null)
            {
                bool matched = condition(item);
                if (!matched) shouldAdd = false;
            }
            if(shouldAdd)  yield return item;
            IEnumerable<T> childEnumerable = childSelector(item);
            if (childEnumerable != null && childEnumerable.Any())
            {
                // Call recursive
                IEnumerable<T> childsMatching = childEnumerable.Recursive(childSelector, condition);
                if (childsMatching != null && childsMatching.Any())
                {
                    foreach (T childMatch in childsMatching)
                    {
                        yield return childMatch;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample calling:

```
        IEnumerable<Person> canVotePersons = data.Recursive(p => p.Children, p => p.Age >= 18);
        foreach(Person voter in canVotePersons)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(voter.Name);
        }

        IEnumerable<Person> allPersons = data.Recursive(p => p.Children);
        foreach (Person person in allPersons)
        {
            listBox2.Items.Add(string.Format("Name: {0} Age: {1}", person.Name, person.Age));
        }
```